# grant command is not working in shell script because of syntax error

Tags: shell

I am stuck with an issue with shell scripting.

I have already used `\` character before double quotes `(")` because of some reason, as in the following line of my shell script.

> sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_user}@\${host} identified by \${dbpass};\";

But as in the MySQL "grant" command syntax, I need to put double quotes before and after `\${dbpass}`, which is the part of the shell script line I given above.When I put like this, `\"\${dbpass}\"`, it is throwing syntax error during execution.What should I need to solve this.

This is an update.
This is the shell script which I want to run.

> ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
>   su root -c "
>     echo \"Give db name :\";
>     read db_name;
>     echo \"Give password :\";
>     read db_pass;
>     host=localhost;
>     sql1=\"create database \$db_name;\";
>     sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_name}@\${host} identified by \"\${db_pass}\";\";
>     sql3=\"\${sql1}\${sql2}\";
>     echo \"==============\";
>     mysql -u root -p -e \"\${sql3}\";
>   ";
>   '

Please refer this script and please let me know the necessary changes i need to do with this.

Thanks.

Comment: The variables you mention `$db_name` etc, they are coming from the shellscript right? Secondly, does it really _need_ to be double quotes? Isn't single quotes supported? What is giving the syntax error, the script? How do you pass this to _something_ and what is _something_?

Comment: sql2 is a bash variable?

Comment: @DavideBerra: I dunno who you'r reffering to, but I can't see anything specific making it a _bash_ variable. Rather a shell variable :)

Comment: Please have a look on my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db_name="yourdbname"
db_user="yourdbuser"
host="yourhost"
dbpass="yourdbpass"

sql2="grant all on ${db_name}.* to ${db_user}@${host} identified by ${dbpass};"

echo $sql2 | mysql -u yourusername -pmysql
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay davide.But please have a look on my updated question.